# when is Implementation of example into LATEX2e?

Tags: algorithm2e

**When the write into texwork the following :**

```
 \begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{this text}
\KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
initialization\;
\While{not at end of this document}{
read current\;
\eIf{understand}{
go to next section\;
current section becomes this one\;
}{
go back to the beginning of current section\;
}
}
\caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}
```

**error occurs:**

This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013062820 (rev 4627) 
I can't find the format file `miktex-luatex.fmt'!
  What is the reason?
Please .... Do I find help??

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you please show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution?

Comment: it not run ,When I write in my texworks shows a error.I can't find the format file `miktex-luatex.fmt'!

Comment: The message indicates you are trying to run `luatex` on what is presumably a LaTeX (or LuaLaTeX?) file: have you tried `lualatex` from the TeXworks dropdown? That may solve the issues, but it does sound as if something is up with your LuaTeX installation. I'd try using the MiKTeX settings and choosing 'Rebuild formats'